# Not booting after finishing installing fedora 37

Tags: linux, boot, fedora

On the first reboot after installing Fedora 37, I got this error and I can't boot the system.
It says: "This is not a bootable disk"

- I used Ventoy to make a bootable usb.
- I deleted Window "C" partition, then created "boot", "boot/efi", "/", "/home".

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps the best you can do is to restore Windows from the PC rescue disk or from an image. From your question, it does not seem you have the ability to install another OS.

Comment: This ^^^ or use the automatic installer... BTW, "boot/efi" seems to be a mount point of the ESP (that you didn't mention so supposedly didn't create?), required for any modern system. This is likely the reason for the comment above.